# Lumen job dispatching done without database Queue Driver

Tags: laravel, lumen, guzzle, jwt

What do I have:

- Lumen service which processing particular Job
- Laravel portal which sending file to that service for processing by it

Once it was using only JS and Ajax it worked almost fine - the only what I had to implement is CORS middleware. However after I moved logic to JWT (using `jwt-auth` package) and GuzzleHttp (I'm using it to send requests to service API) Job stopped processing throught database queue instead it running as if Queue driver being set to `sync`.

Following is controller which I'm calling during API call:

```
public function processPackageById(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->package_id;
    $package = FilePackage::where('id', '=', $id)->where('package_status_id', '=', 1)->first();

    if($package) {
        Queue::push(new PackageProcessingJob(
            $this->firm,
            $this->accounts,
            $package
        ));

        return 'dispatching done for ' . $id;
    }
    return 'dispatching not done for ' . $id;
}
```

where `$this->firm` and `$this->accounts` are injected Repositories for particular models. `FilePackage` object being created on Laravel site and both shares same database to work with.

As result no job being incerted into `jobs` table. When I use Postman everything is fine. However when I'm trying to send request from Laravel backend:

```
public function uploaderPost(Request $request)
{
    // Here we get auth token and put into protected valiable `$this->token`
    $this->authorizeApi(); 

    $requestData = $request->except('_token');


    $package = $requestData['file'];

    $uploadPackageRequest =
        $this->client->request('POST', config('bulk_api.url') .'/api/bulk/upload?token=' . $this->token,
            [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'file',
                    'contents' => fopen($package->getPathName(), 'r'),
                    'filename' => $package->getClientOriginalName(),
                ],
            ]
        ]);
    $uploadPackageRequestJson = json_decode($uploadPackageRequest->getBody()->getContents());
    $uploadPackageRequestStatus = $uploadPackageRequestJson->status;

    if($uploadPackageRequestStatus == 1) {
        $package = BulkUploadPackage::where('id', '=',$uploadPackageRequestJson->id)->first();

        // If package is okay - running it
        if($package !== null){
            // Here where I expect job to be dispatched (code above)
            $runPackageRequest =
                $this->client->request('POST', config('api.url') .'/api/bulk/run?token=' . $this->token,
                    [
                        'multipart' => [
                            [
                                'name' => 'package_id',
                                'contents' => $package->id
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]);


            // Here I'm receiving stream for some reason
            dd($runPackageRequest->getBody());

            if($runPackageRequest->getStatusCode()==200){
                return redirect(url('/success'));
            }
        }
    }
    return back();
}
```

Could anyone advise me what is wrong here and what causes the issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it was really interesting. After echoing `config('queue.default')` in my contoller it appeared that it's value indeed `sync` nevertheless that I set everything correctly.

Then I assumed that maybe the reason in Laravel itself and its variables. Indeed in `.env` file from Laravel side `QUEUE_DRIVER` being set to `sync`. After I changed it to `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` everything started working as expected.

Hope that will help someone in future.